# JavaScript validation form for big decimal

Tags: javascript, validation, decimal

I have a form validated by a script, the value of the form cannot be greater than 5. But if you enter 5.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 the form is validated and the value is rounded, how can I do the validation with a large number of decimal places without rounded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by simply splitting the numeric string after the dot (comma). With extreme data entered into the form, the fractional part is validated

```
function validateY(inp) {
    let elemY = ($('#y_set'))
    let c = (inp.value.replace(',','.'))
    c = c.split('.')
    c = Number(c[1])
    let val = Number((inp.value.replace(',','.')))
    if ( isNaN(val) || typeof(val) != "number" || elemY.val()==="" ){
            return false
    }else if (val === 5 && c > 0)  {
        return false
    }else if (val === -3 && c > 0)  {
        return false
    }
    return val <= 5 && val >= -3
}
```

c variable - (String split into integer and fraction).
5 and -3 are the extreme values ​​allowed in the form

Sorry if the code is bad, I'm still learning

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the Math.round() function. It rounds your decimal number to a whole number. In your case, it will round it down to 5.
So, your code would look something like this:

```
let val = Math.round(5.00000000000000000000000000000000000000001) 
console.log (val)
//Expected output : 5
```

Do take a look at this link for better understanding.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Answer (score 0):

First I must ask do you actually need number precision this large? It seems impractical to me.

JS numbers are all treated as [IEEE 754 floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) internally, aka `Float64`. This format is only capable of storing around 15-17 significant decimal digits. For you case, the best effort it can store is `5.000000000000001` with 14 zeros, put in more zeros it'll exceed it's precision storing capacity and be discarded.

So under the hood the number is not rounded, it's actually information lost, the final piece `...001` has no place to be stored so discarded, leaving `5.0000...000`.

Back to your question. If you really need a solution to store number with very large precision, take a look at `bignumber.js` lib, take a look at the [docs](http://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js). It can store number in arbitrary finite precision (but not infinite, like `1/3 = 0.333...33`).

Instead of JS primitive `number` type, the number will be represented as a `BigNumber` object, which takes more memory space and calculates slower. You cannot use normal arithmetic operators like `+-*/` nor `!==, ===`. You must go like `BigNumber.plus(x)` or `BigNumber.eq(x)`.

So you sacrifice ease of use, speed and memory efficiency for large precision. It's a trade-off you need to evaluate whether your use case worth it.